# Count method throws syntax error when used with where clause in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using loopback/strong loop in node.js. 
I am trying to use where clause in count method for paginition purpose. Whenever I try to use where clause, it gives me a mysql syntax error for as simple query as below.

```
Ride.count({
where:{"id":20}
},function(err,totalCount){
if (err) {
log.info("Total error ", err);
fn(err);
}else {
log.info("Total count ", totalCount);
}
});
```

this is the error I get.

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '20' at line 1\n at Query.Sequence._packetToError (D:\Code\liftee\rest-services\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:48:14)\n at Query.ErrorPacket (D:\Code\liftee\rest-services\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:83:18)\n at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\Code\liftee\rest-services\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:271:23)\n at Parser.write (D:\Code\liftee\rest-services\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:77:12)\n at Protocol.write (D:\Code\liftee\rest-services\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)\n at Socket. (D:\Code\liftee\rest-services\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:92:28)\n at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)\n at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)\n at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)\n at TCP.onread (net.js:529:20)\n --------------------\n at Protocol._enqueue (D:\Code\liftee\rest-services\node_modules\loopback-co
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try without using where clause. I have tested this on my model and it works.

```
Ride.count(
  {"id":20},
  function(err,totalCount){
    if (err) {
      log.info("Total error ", err);
      fn(err);
    }else {
      log.info("Total count ", totalCount);
    }
  }
);
```

Have a look at the strongloop API explorer. You only need to pass value to count function.